# Group a 2D array

Tags: ruby, arrays, grouping

I have the following kind of array

```
[[y,x], [y,w], [m,e], [m,t],[a,b]]
```

How would I turn it to

```
[[y, [x,w]], [m, [e,t]], [a,[b]]
```

essentially grouping all arrays by their 1st element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
a = [['y','x'], ['y','w'], ['m','e'], ['m','t'],['a','b']]
a.group_by(&:first).map { |c, xs| [c, xs.map(&:last)] }
# => [["y", ["x", "w"]], ["m", ["e", "t"]], ["a", ["b"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed exactly this question and answer for [grouped_options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select) so my form select used an optgroup to arrange my list of products by their category to make things a little more user-friendly.

All the examples use extremely inefficient queries to populate the grouped options and I knew there had to be something more efficient - that used just one database query - to populate the 2D array required by `grouped_options_for_select`. I've been looking for a while so was pleased to find this thread.

Thanks to @falsetru.
This is my solution

Controller:

```
@product = params[:product]
products = Product.joins(:product_type).pluck('product_types.name', :name)
@grouped_products = products.group_by { |product_type| product_type.shift }
```

I found these examples which were extremely helpful: http://jelera.github.io/howto-work-with-ruby-group-by and for the grouped options I didn't need to do the final flatten because we may wish to have a display/value pair for each element (which you could just pluck after `:name`).

HTML/ERB:

```
<select name="product" id="product" class="form-select">
   <%= grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_products, @product) %>
</select>
```

I know this isn't exactly related to the question, but I thought I'd leave my answer here in case it helps someone in a similar predicament to me.